# In how many ways can $3$ red , $2$ yellow , $5$ green ,and $2$ blue balls be seated at a square table , with three balls on each side of the table.

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

> In how many ways can $3$ red , $2$ yellow , $5$ green ,and $2$ blue balls be seated at a square table , with three balls on each side of the table. (Each ball in the same color will be seen as indistinguishable )

**My try:** We cannot distinguish the sides of a square ,so select a random side. After that , select one of the three possible position to put the first ball. It can be done $3$ ways such that the first , the last and the middle place. We have $4$ choices to put a ball in the initial seat , so the rest will be arranged as to which color initial ball is selected. Then my answer is $$3 \times \bigg[\frac{11!}{5!(2!)^3}+\frac{11!}{5!3!2!}+\frac{11!}{(2!)^2(3!)(4!)}+\frac{11!}{5!3!2!}\bigg]$$

Is my solution correct ?

**ADDENDUM:** I think there is a missing part in my question such that whether the the rotatitons can be seen as distinct as @ThomasAndrews mentioned. However , the book does not say anything extra. When i look at other question in my book , i dont see any rotation etc , so lets assume that we do not rotate it !

**ADDENDUM 2:** What if we can see the rotation as distinct , as @ThomasAndrews mentioned . What would happen ?

**Similar question in my book**

> In how many ways can $12$ people be seated at a square table, with three
> persons on each side of the table?

ANSWER OF THE BOOK:

> There are now $3$ ways—the left, middle, or right seat—to seat person #1, and $11!$ ways to seat the remaining people. This gives $3 ⋅ 11!$
> seatings

Comment: Have you considered that adjacent balls of the same colour are indistinguishable such that two blue balls next to each other individually can be arranged two ways but are only perceived as a single combination?

Comment: @Johnson as i wrote  , two balls  in the same color are indistinguishable , please read the question carefully

Comment: I see, thank you for clarifying, I misinterpreted what you were saying.

Comment: Does rotating a seating 90 degrees count as a different seating? Because as written, it is unclear why it matters that the table is a square - it might have been a circle with 12 seats, for example.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the books does not say anything extra

Comment: @ThomasAndrews By a square table there are $4$ arrangements and by a circle $12$. I think that difference is essential.

Comment: "We cannot distinguish the sides of the squares." That's a weird assumption, and implies things you might not mean. The sides certainly have an order, so given a side, there is an opposite side.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes we cannot distinguish ,so i wrote my solution for this , please read my try

Comment: @drhab Well, the question doesn't say that rotation is the same arrangement, which is what I was getting at. In the most bullet-headed reading of this question, the answer is just $\frac{12!}{3!2!5!2!}.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I think that meant is: none of the $4$ sides serves as orientation (so be aware of multiple counting).

Comment: I can't tell if your answer makes sense until I understand the question, or at least how you are interpreting the question @GioavanniGiorgio

Comment: @drhab Except that isn't part of the question, it is part of the OPs attempt at an answer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews please , look at trueblue anils' PS , in my question identical under rotation

Answer (score 2):

Make a row of the $12$ balls. There are $\frac{12!}{3!2!5!2!}$ distinct configurations. Now fix some seat (e.g. the leftmost of the north side). Place the utmost left ball of the row on that seat and wrap the row counterclockwise so that all balls are eventually placed on a seat.

To repair multiple counting we must divide by $4$ (because there are $4$ seats that by rotation can be placed on leftmost of the north side) so the final answer is:$$\frac14\frac{12!}{3!2!5!2!}$$

Observe that reasoning like that by $12$ distinct colors would yield the result $\frac14\cdot12!=3\times11!$ which agrees with the answer of the book that you published in your second addendum.

Comment: Note that the division by 4 works in this case because none of the arrangements of balls have rotational symmetry due to there being an odd number of red balls (and of green balls). Each arrangement occurs in exactly four visually distinguishable orientations. If the colours all occurred an even number of times then you could arrange them in a pattern with 180-degree symmetry, and those arrangements occur in only 2 distinguishable orientations rather than 4.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Yes Jaap. You are right. The fact that e.g. there are $5$ green balls made it clear to me that in this context we don't have to bother about these "possibilities"

Comment: End of a confused trail ! (+1)$\;\;$  :)